# How to keep other divs from moving when using slidetoggle in responsive grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a responsive grid in place, and on desktop/tablet there are 3 columns per row. Each div in said column has hidden content that can be expanded vertically when a button is clicked using slideToggle. I only want the div that is below it, that it touches, to move down. However, the entire row below it moves down.

Here is my fiddle & the JS I am using:
https://jsfiddle.net/6yz5okx3/

```
$( ".slidetoggle" ).click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find( ".av_inner_wrapper" ).slideToggle();
});
```

If you click on the third item in the first row, you'll see that the div expands but I only want it to push down the div directly underneath it, not the whole row. Any thoughts?

P.S. This is in Wordpress, so all of the extra divs & such are put in there using the grid builder I'm using. I don't have very much flexibility with them.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can't using the grid you currently have. You'll  need to use a column-based layout (not row-based), or absolute position all elements using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rnevius is correct with his comment that you cannot do that with your current system.

You could try something like CSS Columns. However, [CSS Column Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) is spotty for anything other than the most current browser versions.

The Below Snippet demonstrates the CSS Columns.

```js
$( ".slidetoggle" ).click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find( ".av_inner_wrapper" ).slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-width: 33%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-width: 33%; /* Firefox */
    column-width: 33%;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 0; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 0;
}
.one-third {
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -o-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -ms-column-break-inside:avoid; column-break-inside:avoid;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:auto;
}
.av_inner_wrapper {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="one-third">
  <div>
   <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h3>Heading 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <section>
    <div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit</p>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <div>
    <button href="#">CTA</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="av_icon_outer_wrapper">
   <button class="slidetoggle">Click to Slide</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="one-third">
  <div>
   <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h3>Heading 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <section>
    <div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit</p>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <div>
    <button href="#">CTA</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="av_icon_outer_wrapper">
   <button class="slidetoggle">Click to Slide</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="one-third">
  <div>
   <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h3>Heading 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <section>
    <div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit</p>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <div>
    <button href="#">CTA</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="av_icon_outer_wrapper">
   <button class="slidetoggle">Click to Slide</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="one-third">
  <div>
   <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h3>Heading 4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <section>
    <div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit</p>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <div>
    <button href="#">CTA</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="av_icon_outer_wrapper">
   <button class="slidetoggle">Click to Slide</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="one-third">
  <div>
   <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h3>Heading 5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <section>
    <div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit</p>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <div>
    <button href="#">CTA</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="av_icon_outer_wrapper">
   <button class="slidetoggle">Click to Slide</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="one-third">
  <div>
   <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h3>Heading 6</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <section>
    <div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit lorem ipsum dolor sit amit</p>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
  <div class="av_inner_wrapper">
   <div>
    <button href="#">CTA</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="av_icon_outer_wrapper">
   <button class="slidetoggle">Click to Slide</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. Luckily, I don't need to support the older browsers :)

Comment: @LindseyS - I'm glad this may help you out. Please mark this answer as accepted if it ends up solving your problem so that others do not spend their time trying to solve a problem that has already been solved.